# What is correct syntax for accessing .csv file as a list in .py program? (If possible)

Tags: python, list, csv

This syntax works for me when using a list. 
My list is now so long it is unpractical to keep it in the program itself. Could I have a csv-file of one single column, where I could call element "i" - MyCSVfile(i) - in MyCSVfile?

```
import math
i = 0
while i < len(MyFile.csv):
    Access element i in MyFile.csv
    i += 1
```

If so what is the syntax change? (If it helps, the .csv file is in the same folder as the .py program)

**Note!** I do not need to change the .csv file, just read it. Preferably also get the length as you can with len(list).

Comment: https://learnbatta.com/blog/reading-and-writing-csv-files-using-python-12/  may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read a csv file, you need code like so:

```
f = open("mycsvfile.csv", "rb")
reader = csv.reader(f)
for line in reader:
    do_something(line)
```

Comment: Thanks! I used a slight alteration, but now it works! :D

Comment: My code: import math
import csv

with open('6.csv','rt')as f:
  data = csv.reader(f)
  for row in data:
        print(row)

Comment: Hmm. When the "do_something(line) is written as print(row) I get ["8"] for example - how can I just extract the integer 8, instead of the string ["8"]?

Comment: It's a string in a list, so int(row[0]) will get you the integer conversion of the first element of the row list.